# Display bitmap in a WPF image control

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have a bitmap that is created in memory (using graphics drawing to add lines etc to it). I can save it no problem using

```
bmp.Save(@"Path");
```

I want to display it in my WPF window, the only example I have found which seems to do what I want is

```
Bitmap bmp = someClass.returnMap(); // returns a Bitmap which has been drawn
bmp.Save(@"Path"); //Just so I know the bitmap isn't null
ImageSourceConverter isc = new ImageSourceConverter();
image.Source = (ImageSource)isc.ConvertFrom(bmp); //I get a null refrence exception here
```

I have no idea why I am getting a null reference or why there is so much conflicting information when I try and Google this.

**Edit**
Error message as requested

'An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.'

Comment: please show use the full error stack maybe we can find something in it

Comment: Added the error message

Comment: Looks like `image` is null. You can easily find that out by debugging your code.